# display json data in grid view from server using .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, gridview

I have been created simple shopify app to retrieve product details.

When i access code from gihub.

It run successfully and display product details in text box.

I need to simple change to show the product details in grid view.

Here is dafault.aspx:

existing code;

default.aspx:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" codefile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SampleWebApplication._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="APIOutput" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my output screenshot http://s22.postimg.org/xj9zacxa9/untitled.jpg

I need to display product details in gridview,

default.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ShopifyAPIAdapterLibrary;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace SampleWebApplication
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShopifyAuthorizationState state = HttpContext.Current.Session["Shopify.AuthState"] as ShopifyAuthorizationState;
            ShopifyAPIClient client
                = new ShopifyAPIClient(state);
            APIOutput.Text = (string)client.Get("/admin/products.json");
        }
    }
}
```

but I just confused with codefile, Can anyone help me get the product details in gridview?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a gridview control, deserialize the JSON into a list of objects, bind the list to the gridview.

Comment: actually i m new to .net.. can you please guide me ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" codefile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SampleWebApplication._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>

    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and default.cs code as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ShopifyAPIAdapterLibrary;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace SampleWebApplication
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShopifyAuthorizationState state = HttpContext.Current.Session["Shopify.AuthState"] as ShopifyAuthorizationState;
            ShopifyAPIClient client
                = new ShopifyAPIClient(state);
            string shopData = (string)client.Get("/admin/products.json");
            JavascriptSerializer serializer = new JavascriptSerializer();
            // Here Product is a object class which contains all of the attribute that JSON has.
            List<Product> lstProduct = serializer.Deserialize<Product>(shopData);
            GridView1.DataSource = lstProduct;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

and the product class look like this :

```
public Class Product
{
  // Here is all the properties you want to discribed.
  // This property is same as the property available in your JSON file.
}
```

Hopefully this will help.

Comment: You need to add Reference for JavascriptSerializer, for this add System.Web.Extensions.dll in your reference and resolve the reference error. And for Product, Product is a class which you need to create and inside this class the attributes are the attributes available into your JSON.

Comment: hi.. if i add System.Web.Extensions.dll .. it shows this website already referenced assembly..

Comment: Please use JavaScriptSerializer. There is spell error that;s why I think you are not getting proper reference.

Comment: for more information :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: can you send me the screenshot.. if the *.dll is already in reference then just right click on JavaScriptSerializer and go to resolve option and its all done.

Comment: product is user class. You need to create a class with name Product.

Comment: sorry.. i don't know.. can you please edit your post and show me... and also  i got error, this line serializer(shopData); like,, serializr is a variable not a method...

Comment: It look your Product class not mapped properly with JSON object.

Comment: Can you send me your JSON object so I can verify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103368/discussion-between-pcs-and-arpit-jain).